# Using form values javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to access form data through a Javascript function when an input is 'changed'.
Currently I use something like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="type" name="myValue" onchange="myFunction(this.form)>
</form>

<script>
    function myFunction(form) {
        var value = form.type.value;
    }
</script>
```

And it works, however instead of writing

```
var value = form.type.value;
```

I need to write something like this

```
var myArray = ["type"];
var value = form.myArray[0].value;
```

Which is not working. Is this due to how values in arrays are handled?
I have it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yj315aj7/) on JSFiddle if that is useful.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var value = form[myArray[0]].value;
```

`form.myArray[0]` is first getting the member myArray from form, and then trying to get the first item in that. Equal to `(form.myArray)[0]`

`form[myArray[0]]` explicitly says get the member from form which is of the name of the value inside `myArray[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can access properties of object using `[]` like this:

```
var value = form["type"].value;
// equivalent to:
var value = form.type.value
```

In your case this should work:

```
var myArray = ["type"];
var value = form[myArray[0]].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

'myArray' is declared as a local variable but it is NOT form's property.
So form.myArray will fail.